# c++: A function pointer as a parameter. But the function being pointed is declared with Parent class, actual function is given with Child class

Tags: c++, c++11

Its like a riddle. So lets explain one by one.

- I have a driver function(`fD`) which receives a function pointer and calls it multiple times in `while` loop.
- The function pointer(`fP`) has a parameter of `class A`.
- There are 3 child classes of `class A`, `class B,C,D`.
- I want `fP` to be able to receive all child classes `B,C,D` in place of parameter `A`.
- Sqwiggle error saying `B` doesn't match with `A`.

And of course an example is better than a riddle.

```
class A {};
class B : A { /* some function */ };
class C : A { /* some function */ };
class D : A { /* some function */ };

void fD(A a, void (*fP)(A))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fP(a);
    }
}

void PointedFunction(B b)
{
    /* Do Something with the B function */
}

void PointedFunction2(C c)
{
    /* Do Something with the C function */
}

void PointedFunction3(D d)
{
    /* Do Something with the D function */
}
int main()
{
    // What i want to do
    B b;
    fD(b, &PointedFunction);
    C c;
    fD(c, &PointedFunction);
    D d;
    fD(d, &PointedFunction);
    // But sqwiggle at & saying argument don't match

    return 0;
};
```

Question: How can I use child classes in place of parent class in a function pointer?

I'm prettry sure the cause is because I'm trying to use a child class. Since c++ is very strict about these stuff. But... I don't know how to solve this.

Also, as long as i know, what I'm doing looks very inappropriate to me. Is this like.. legal?

Comment: Did you forget that a `class` makes everything -- including inheritance -- `private` by default? Or is the issue that you are passing by value instead of by reference? Hmm.. quite the riddle...

Comment: You should read about object slicing and then consider that you probably want that parameter to be a reference if you plan to pass subclasses to it.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes I forgot about that. I will check that cause.

Comment: @JaMiT It seems that is not the cause. I changed every inheirtence to public explicitly, but   no change.

Comment: Have you tried to pass pointer instead of value or reference? Something like `void PointedFunction(A* a)`

Comment: @PeterLee a reference would work just fine: `void fD(void (*fP)(A&)) ... void PointedFunction(A& a)`

Comment: I edited my example code so that it better describes the situation. But I think I actually made it worse. How do I revert the edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you may want to do:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public A {};

void fD(A& instance, void (*fP)(A&))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fP(instance);
    }
}

void PointedFunction(A& a)
{
    /* Do Something with the A family */
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    fD(b, &PointedFunction);
    C c;
    fD(c, &PointedFunction);
    D d;
    fD(d, &PointedFunction);

    return 0;
};
```

Alternatively, if you have specialized methods for `B` and `C`, you may use generics instead of a class hierarchy.

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

template<class T>
void fD(T& instance, void (*fP)(T&))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fP(instance);
    }
}

void PointedFunction(B& a)
{
    /* Do Something with B */
}

void PointedFunction(C& a)
{
    /* Do Something with C */
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    fD(b, &PointedFunction);
    C c;
    fD(c, &PointedFunction);

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What if it needed to be `void pointedFunction(B& b)` because I needed to call `b.OnlyBFunction()`?.

Comment: but then you mentioned you want to work with `A family`. The `OnlyBFunction()` is not part of interface of `A family`

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry for confusing you. I was confused my self when asking the question... Then I must change `A family` to `B interface` for something.

Comment: see my updates!